# How to migrate from RAMJobStore to JobStoreCMT for persisted Quartz jobs in Seam

Tags: java, seam, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am trying to get a simple example of the Quartz scheduler working in JBoss Seam 2.2.0.GA. Everything works fine using the RAMJobStore setting, but changing the store from

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

to

```
org.quartz.jobStore.class org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.PostgreSQLDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource quartzDatasource
## FIXME Should be a different datasource for the non managed connection.
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource quartzDatasource
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix qrtz_
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDatasource.jndiURL java:/quartzDatasource
```

allows the scheduler to start up, but whereas the job was previously being triggered and run at the correct interval, now it is not run at all. There is also nothing persisted to the quartz database.

I am aware that the nonManagedTXDataSource shouldn't be the same as the managed datasource, but I am having issues with the datasource being unable to be found by Quartz, even though there is a message earlier on reporting it being bound successfully (this is probably about to be asked in a separate question). Using the same datasource allows the service to start up without errors.

My components.xml file has the following:

```
<event type="org.jboss.seam.postInitialization"> 
   <action execute="#{asyncResultMapper.scheduleTimer}"/> 
</event>
<async:quartz-dispatcher/>
```

and ASyncResultMapper has the following:

```
@In
ScheduleProcessor processor;
private String text = "ahoy";
private QuartzTriggerHandle quartzTriggerHandle;

public void scheduleTimer() {
    String cronString = "* * * * * ?";
    quartzTriggerHandle = processor.createQuartzTimer(new Date(), cronString, text);
}
```

and ScheduleProcessor is as follows:

```
@Name("processor")
@AutoCreate
@Startup
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
public class ScheduleProcessor { 

    @Asynchronous
    public QuartzTriggerHandle createQuartzTimer(@Expiration Date when, @IntervalCron String interval, String text) {
        process(when, interval, text);
        return null;
    }

    private void process(Date when, String interval, String text) {
        System.out.println("when = " + when);
        System.out.println("interval = " + interval);
        System.out.println("text = " + text);
    }
}
```

The logs show the service starting but nothing about the job:

```
INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 Volatile Trigger(s).
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 Volatile Job(s).
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] JobStoreCMT initialized.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Freed 0 triggers from 'acquired' / 'blocked' state.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Recovering 0 jobs that were in-progress at the time of the last shut-down.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Recovery complete.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 'complete' triggers.
INFO  [JobStoreCMT] Removed 0 stale fired job entries.
INFO  [QuartzScheduler] Scheduler FlibScheduler$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

I'm sure it's probably something trivial I've missed, but I can't find a solution in the forums anywhere.

Comment: When using CMT Quartz doesn't handle transactions, it's the responsibility of Seam. So your createQuartzTimer should run inside a TX. AFAIK there is no already running TX at postInitialization. Did you try putting @Transactional on createQuartzTimer?

Comment: Adding @Transactional didn't start the job. Whichever annotation is used, the method is still called (checked with simple logging statements).

Comment: I've tested this setup: JBoss EAP 5.1.1 + Seam 2.2.2 + quartz 1.6.5 + Postgresql 9.1 (we use it in our project) and it works fine. Your logs show that you are using the older 1.5.2 version of quartz that is bundled with JBoss AS, but Seam is tested against 1.6 api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this for myself in the end. The issue of the JobStoreCMT version not starting and triggering jobs was caused by a mixture of a missing @Transactional (thanks tair), and more importantly a need to upgrade Quartz. Once Quartz was upgraded to 1.8.5 the error messages became a lot more useful.

Comment: I think you actually meant @Transactional